# FB Share pop-up different window than what is posted

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, share-button

I'm new to using the FB share buttons terminology so forgive me if I use the wrong syntax in describing this.

My site is setup to load pages based on the passed parameters in the URL (...?page=somepage&imageid=idnum).

So I have my index file which contains my head, as well as sidebar, etc. Then my main body  is generated according to the passed parameter. Simple Enough.

On the homepage, the main body is a gallery of images.  When they click on one of those images it takes them to a page that just displays that one image. The page is loaded with parameters of ?page=detail&image_id=1 /*or whatever the id of that image is */

So when they click on the share on FB button on those individual images page, I would like it to populate with the image that is displayed on that page.  What I have done is included a php file in my head tag.  The php script included gets the page info and passed parameters and then fills out the image url based on the imageid.

```
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.chiseledimages.com/clients/vote/'.$imgurl.'"/>';
```

This works in that when displaying the page source, the meta tag with og:image shows perfectly, also in that when I run it through the FB Object debugger, it gets the correct image and doesn't show me any errors.  It even posts the correct image when the users shares on their wall.  What is does not do, is show the correct image in the pop window after the uses presses the share button on my site.  So even though the result is what I want, the problem with the user not seeing the correct image in the share pop-up, may lead them not to want to share on their wall.

Current location of site: http://www.chiseledimages.com/clients/vote/
Example of a specific pages: http://chiseledimages.com/clients/vote/?page=detail&angel_id=1

Screenshots of pop-up with wrong image, but final posted story having correct image.
[image: Facebook_wrong_image]

How can I make the image in the pop-up match the image that is going to be shared. Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to mention and I'm sure it matters that I'm using Addthis to implement the FB share.

Comment: Specify the image that is to be shown on the popup through its properties?

Comment: I would recommend using the new [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui) javascript implementation for more control

Answer (score 0):

Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ - look for the 'picture' parameter description

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use this http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365475-attribute-based-configuration#.UwPQB6LW6So. just follow their example and you good to go.